# DoesNotExist at /settings : Profile matching query does not exist

Tags: django

```
@login_required(login_url='signin')
def settings(request):

user_profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)

  if request.method == 'POST':

        if request.FILES.get('image') == None:
            image = user_profile.profileimg
            bio = request.POST['bio']
            location = request.POST['location']

            user_profile.profileimg = image
            user_profile.bio = bio
            user_profile.location = location
            user_profile.save()

        if request.FILES.get('image') !=None:
            image = request.FILES.get('image')
            bio = request.POST['bio']
            location = request.POST['location']

            user_profile.profileimg = image
            user_profile.bio = bio
            user_profile.location = location
            user_profile.save()
```

return render(request, 'setting.html', {'user_profile' :user_profile})

```
            

user_profile = Profile.objects.get(user_profile=request.user)
```

Hello i am trying to run this code for a social app i am creating and i cant proceed further because i keep getting an error message and i cant proceed.
please i need help with this thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear: the user which is making the request doesn't have a `Profile` associated with it.

You should handle the case in which the profile does not exist.

```
try:
    user_profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
except:
    # handle user_profile creation here
    user_profile = Profile(user=request.user, ...)
```

Or use https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create

Or have a have a `post_save` signal that automatically creates a Profile for each user, if it doesn't exist already.